# Enable specific CSS Code for Visitors and specific Roles

Tags: css, user-roles

how i can enable an specific css code for visitors and an specific user role

for example this code:

```css
input[type=radio] {
    border: 1px solid !important;
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to do the opposite and make that radio border solid for all people, except logged in users who are not in a specific role. if you built your theme correctly then logged in users will have a `logged-in` class on the `body` tag that you can use to target non-visitors to undo the change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom css on your html header using wp_head hook action & checking your current User Role

```
add_action('wp_head', 'add_css_of_current_specific_user_role');
function add_css_of_current_specific_user_role()
{ 
    /*Check Current User is Login*/
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) 
    {  
       $user = wp_get_current_user();
       /*Check Current User Role*/
       if (in_array('visitor', $user->roles)) { ?>

            <style>
              // Some CSS
            </style>

    <?php } 

    }
}
```

Comment: ty for your answer but the the role visitor doesent exist. fist i wanna only for my guests/visitor show an specific css code

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have specific CSS for visitors (aka not logged users) then you can take @HK89's code and tweak it a bit

```
add_action('wp_head', 'add_css_of_current_specific_user_role');
function add_css_of_current_specific_user_role()
{ 
    /*Check if it's a visitor*/
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) 
    {  ?>
        <style>
            // Some CSS
        </style>
    <?php } 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried this code in the functions.php for showing to the guests this css

how is that possible

```
add_action('init', 'check_if_user_is_loggedin_function');
function check_if_user_is_loggedin_function()
{
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) 
    {
} 
    else {
    echo '<style>
            .woo-variation-swatches.wvs-style-squared .variable-items-wrapper .variable-item.button-variable-item-offen {
            display: none;
            }
            .woo-variation-swatches.wvs-style-squared .variable-items-wrapper .variable-item.color-variable-item-offen {
            display: none;
            }
        </style>';
}
}
```